# How do I fix this with 'find & replace' on MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

I scrape information from certain websites and would like to remove some paragraph breaks when I paste it. The information is then pasted as such:

Text

> paragraph break (x2)

Text

> paragraph break (x2)

Text

> paragraph break (x4)

Text

> paragraph break (x19)

Text (rinse & repeat)

How do I fix this? I know I need to replace ^p with nothing to erase individual paragraph breaks, but it becomes complex when the paragraph breaks are not consistent. Help appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Use wildcard.

Find what:

- All paragraph breaks: `(^13)\1@`
- All line breaks: `(^l)\1@`
- Mixed: `[^l^13]{2,}`

Replace with: `^p`

| break | Normal | Wildcard |
| --- | --- | --- |
| paragraph break | `^p` | `^13` |
| line break | `^l` | `^l` |

[Find and Replace Dialogue Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdYk9.png)

Comment: what does \1@ mean in your find formula?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want existing text to remain in separate paragraphs but no blank paragraphs in-between, try this wildcard find and replace:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFtiV.png)